# How to render ggplot2 graphics correctly into word with R markdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ms-word, r-markdown, knitr

I face some problems when rendering ggplot2 graphics into MS Word Documents:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Philipp"
date: "20 10 2021"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

### R Markdown

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

a <- rep(1:50, 200)

b <- sample(x= c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), size= 100000, replace= TRUE)

c <- rep(1000:1049, 200)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c) 

ggplot(df, aes(x= b)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(0, 600)) +
  facet_wrap(~a)+
  geom_text(
    data=df, x=4.5, y=550, aes(label=c), size= 3
  )
```

When i knit this code into MS Word the axis text at the y axis overlaps in the word document and sometimes the bars become invisible. I tried to minimize the size of the axis text but this is at the expense of readability. However, in the zoom-mode in RStudio everything works well.

Is there any solution for this problem?

In MS Word the graphics look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a solution:

```
{r, fig.width= 10, fig.height= 7, echo= FALSE}

plotname
```

You can adapt the size of the graphic in the headline of the code chunk. This will translate into `clean(er)` graphics in the MS word document.